# SUBSTRING WITH CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have a column containing two concatenated data separated by a '/', I want to get only what is before '/' that is equal to a column of another table, so I am trying to use SUBSTRING with CHARINDEX, but I think I'm doing something wrong, follow the code.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM arquivo A, tabela_geral B (NOLOCK), campo_concatenado C (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.primeira_parte = SUBSTRING(C.concatenado, 1, CHARINDEX('/', C.concatenado) -1)
AND B.status = 0
AND B.campo = '13'
AND B.numero NOT IN (6, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 91)
```

Comment: The likely issue is C.concatendao contains a row which doesn't have a '/' in it.

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins I would also suggest being careful with that NOLOCK hint. It is more sinister than most people realize. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You also have top 1 with no order by so you have no way to know which row you will get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle rows which don't have '/'

If you consider the values like before '/'

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM arquivo A, tabela_geral B (NOLOCK), campo_concatenado C (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.primeira_parte = COALESCE(SUBSTRING(C.concatenado, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', C.concatenado), 0) -1), C.concatenado)
AND B.status = 0
AND B.campo = '13'
AND B.numero NOT IN (6, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 91)
```

If you consider the values like after '/'

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM arquivo A, tabela_geral B (NOLOCK), campo_concatenado C (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.primeira_parte = SUBSTRING(C.concatenado, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', C.concatenado), 0) -1)
AND B.status = 0
AND B.campo = '13'
AND B.numero NOT IN (6, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 91)
```

And I strongly recommend you to pay attention on Sean Lange comments

Comment: Hey, thank you, I made some adjustments and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this ?

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM arquivo A, tabela_geral B (NOLOCK), campo_concatenado C (NOLOCK)
  WHERE A.primeira_parte = "%/"
  AND B.status = 0
  AND B.campo = '13'
  AND B.numero NOT IN (6, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 91)
```

Comment: This wouldn't produce the same results, if the OP code worked. Also using % without the `LIKE` clause means you are looking for the literal value of %/. I would suspect this wouldn't return any rows.